# Adding an ActiveX dll to a .Net project as reference works on one dev's machine, but not on another one?

Tags: .net, assemblies, reference, activex

Good afternoon,

we're having a semi-weird problem here with a legacy activex dll that needs to be used in a .net project and strangely it works perfectly fine (adding it as a reference and all its functionality) on one developer's machine, but on no other ones, the build-server complains about a faulty reference etc etc.

Whenever e.g. I try to re-add the .dll, I get the following, kinda shy-on-details error-message:

[image]

Any ideas / suggestions why it might not work in e.g. my environment? The project file etc is a standard class library one for .net 3.5, and we all use the same files/code-base.

Cheers & Thanks,
-Jörg

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the developers machines is environment, so you can guess that the developer whose machine it works on has something else set differently.

My guess is that it is either plain old environment (vars maybe) but more likely a dependency in the SapExtractor.dll. Use FileMon when you try to add a reference to see the file that is not getting found.

Also you can use Depends.exe for seeing which files SapExtractor.dll depends on.

Google for both tools, both from MS and very reputable.

Ryan

Comment: Depends & Process Monitor didn't really reveal anything new or helpful, but using the Interop.SapExtractor.dll that was available on the dev's machine where it worked instead of the activex dll itself was kinda a working workaround... not entirely what I was looking for because now we have that -one- environment where we can generate this Interop assembly...